# Where in select with calculated field

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search a value with a where condition, but i dont know how can i do it more efficient.

The main select is:

```
SELECT id_order, round(sum((quantity*pvd)-descuento_alumno),2) as importe  FROM `order_item` group by id_order
```

I want to search, for example, `'11.78'` in this calculated field:

```
round(sum((quantity*pvd)-descuento_alumno),2) as importe
```

Any idea?

Thanks u!

Comment: you can use a stored procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your statement a HAVING clause:

```
SELECT 
  id_order, 
  round(sum((quantity*pvd)-descuento_alumno), 2) as importe  
FROM `order_item` 
GROUP BY id_order
HAVING importe = 11.78
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution works perfectly!!! Thanks u very much!